# How to check the option in drop down and select other option in same drop-down using blazemeter

Tags: selenium, jmeter, dropdown, blazemeter

I have a drop-down i have to compare option in drop-down and select other option in drop-down using blazemeter. For example in drop-down it is selected with one of the option India, now i have to write a condition if option is India then select another option in the drop-down using blazemeter. I have written as first store the all values text in a variable and written if condition as "$(option)" == "$(India)"
Please help me with the answer

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about [Scriptless Functional Tests](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003340818-Creating-Scriptless-Functional-Tests) - I don't think there are pre-defined actions out of the box, the only option I can think of is `Script Eval` action.

See [Implementing Custom JavaScript Actions for Scriptless Testing](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360010594678-Implementing-Custom-JavaScript-Actions-for-Scriptless-Testing) guide for more details.

Going forward be informed that we cannot help you to come up with a proper solution without seeing your code (or pseudo-code) and especially the page [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) (at least partial, related to the dropdown)